# Regex Search Expected Strings Or Byte Like Objects

Tags: python, regex, python-3.5

```
import os
import codecs
import argparse
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Kingsaber\\Desktop\\python_excercises')
a = codecs.open('BeforeKichiku.txt', encoding='utf-8')
p = a.read()
print(p)

import re

#ch = u"I am from 美国。We should be friends. 朋友."

b = re.findall(u"[\u4e00-\u9fff]+", a)
for x in b:
    print(x)
```

**Expected result**: Print everything out in the variable "a" and find all unicode characters between u4e00-\u9fff and print them out below.

**What happens**: The document prints out successfully but the regex search comes up with the error below. If I switch the regex to search the string "ch" everything works as it should. For some reason it isn't working on the Unicode document.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kingsaber/Desktop/destruga3.py", line 15, in <module>
    b = re.findall(u"[\u4e00-\u9fff]+", a)
  File "C:\Users\Kingsaber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\re.py", line 213, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Yes, you are using `print`, not `print()`. And there is no `ur` prefix in Python 3, just drop the `u` prefixes everywhere. But you need to be *specific* and include your actual full error message.

Comment: oh I forgot to fix the print(). How do I get a more detailed error message? It just says invalid syntax before running.

Comment: If you run this with the Python interpreter, it'll give you a specific line number and a `^` caret pointing at the tokenizer position. It'll probably point at the end of the `ur'...'` string because `ur` is not a recognised prefix in Python 3. Just drop the `u`.

Comment: Ok I edited it. This should be a better question

Answer (score 6):

Based on the error:

```
expected string or bytes-like object
```

You just need to transfer the later part as string type of data using str():

```
b = re.findall(u"[\u4e00-\u9fff]+", str(a))
```

Comment: The error refers to the data. I was screen scraping a list of surnames and simply putting str() around the soup fixed the issue for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in the *file object*:

```
a = codecs.open('BeforeKichiku.txt', encoding='utf-8')

# ...

b = re.findall(u"[\u4e00-\u9fff]+", a)
```

Note how `a` is the `codecs.open()` result, and you pass `a` into `re.findall()`. You put the file *contents* in `p` instead. You may want to use more meaningful variable names rather than 1-letter variables so you can spot such errors more easily.

Note that you really shouldn't be using `codecs.open()`; that's an older API from Python 2 that has many issues and has been made obsolete by the [`io` framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) introduced in Python 3 and backported to Python 2. In Python 3, just use the built-in [`open()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) (which is an alias for `io.open()`):

```
with open('BeforeKichiku.txt', encoding='utf-8') as fileobj:
    contents = fileobj.read()
matches = re.findall("[\u4e00-\u9fff]+", contents)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```